# Application Context is failing to load, as it is not finding any qualifying bean of type EntityManager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

While running JUnits, ApplicationContext is not loaded, as it could not find a qualifying bean javax.persistence.EntityManager. However, the application for which the Junit is being written is working. Both the application and JUnits are using the same spring configuration.

My Configuration class looks like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfiguration {

@Autowired private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override @Bean
public CustomRepository<Person> customRepository(){
    return new CustomRepository<>(Person.class, entityManager);
}
```

As you see, I'm able to autowire EntityManager, even though I have not explicitly defined the bean and the application is working without any issues.

Now in my JUnit

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ControllerTest {

@Autowired
private CController controller;
```

As you see both application and my Junit are using same configuration. How ever when running JUnit, I'm seeing

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I could not understand what in the JUnit is causing the isssue, while the aplication is still working.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: How is this related to Spring Data JPA? You shouldn't inject/pass around the `EntityManager` like that. Instead in your `CustomRepository` annotate the `EntityManager` field with `@PersistenceContext` to let Spring do the heavy lifting. Also if you are using Spring Data you shouldn't be needing a custom repository implementation. Remove the `@TestPropertySource` as Spring Boot automatically loads that, and for testing make sure a DB is available (like an inmemory one or docker based one).

Answer (score 0):

it clearly means that `EntityManager` bean is not defined in your application context. 
So either you define it by yourself or let Spring-boot do the lifting(Spring-boot auto config your context based on dependencies in your POM file). If you choose the latter option then one option to get rid of the error by adding H2 DB.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

UPDATE:
In your test, instead of initializing your context using `@ContextConfiguration` do that with `@SpringBootTest` it will bootstrap your entire container(including other beans that are not defined in `AppConfiguration.java`). Read more about in [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try injecting Entity manager directly in CustomRepository with @PersistenceContext. But I don't understand how this setup is working when running Spring boot application, but failing only at JUnit